# Error:(61, 36) error: cannot find symbol variable READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android

Error:(61, 36) error: cannot find symbol variable READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

```
private void getPDF() {
    //for greater than lolipop versions we need the permissions asked on runtime
    //so if the permission is not available user will go to the screen to allow storage permission
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivity(intent);
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you did wrong import.
try `android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

copy and past below code:

```
private void getPDF() {
//for greater than lolipop versions we need the permissions asked on runtime
//so if the permission is not available user will go to the screen to allow storage permission
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
            Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    startActivity(intent);
    return;
}
```